# How to populate the hidden field with data-id when the asp:linkbutton is clicked

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a link button that calls the modal popup and when the linkbutton is clicked i want to take the data-id and assign it to a hiddenfield

here is my link button

```
 <asp:LinkButton title="Redeem" ID="Redeem" runat="server" CommandName="RedeemVoucher"
                            CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "VouID") %>' data-id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "VouID") %>' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                            <asp:Image ID="imgInformation" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/redeem-icon-4.png"
                                AlternateText="Redeem" />
                        </asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use pure **Java script**, you need to use this code :

```
document.getElementsId("Redeem")[0].getAttribute("data-id")
```

If you use **Jquery**, you need to use this code :

```
$('#Redeem').data('data-id');
```

For further information check this : [More sample](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp)